# Rigging a skeleton

Tags: rigging

I bought a human skeleton model with muscles. It has a lot of bones and different muscles. I want to place the model into certain position to show an exercise and hide all the muscles that are not active in the exercise. Then export the `.jpg` and use as a photo. The skeleton is very realistic.

My problem is that the ribs deform badly when I move the arm from T to A position. Is there a way to fix the ribs so they won't deform?

On the picture can be seen deformation of left ribs and right ribs are normal, because the right arm is in T position.

In blue color is Serratus muscle. It moves with the ribs. So if the ribs will not move the muscle should not move also, right?

[image: Ribs]

Comment: How realistic do you want to animate the skeleton? The forearm and the shin have 2 bones and they move when the hand or foot is rotated. And there are the shoulder bones. A normal rig has so-called twist bones (e.g. a subdivided bone for the forearm) to simulate this but the skeleton bones are not visible, so it doesn't have to be super accurate/realistic in terms of bones. I'm not sure if a normal rig works when these bones are visible and there are muscles on top of this. I think you need extra (rig) bones for the muscles.

Comment: Maybe check out [Fredegund - The BlenRig Skeleton](https://blendermarket.com/products/blenrig-skeleton). It is not free of charge and just a skeleton without any muscles but supports the development of the free BlenRig add-on. Here is a demo video: https://youtu.be/WYM5sXICSI4

Comment: I don't need to animate the skeleton, just put into position and make a picture. I'm using Auto-rig Pro for rigging. Fredegund doesn't have muscles, but I need muscles and bones to be seen in picutre.

Comment: If the ribs move when the arm is moved then the weights for the bones are bad. They bones have too much influence. Check the vertex groups. They store the weights for the bones. A non-zero value means that the bone, which has the same name as the vertex group, affects the mesh part. Or in other words: The ribs have vertex groups with weights of the arm bones. You need to remove the weights (keyword "weight painting").

Comment: If you only need an image and no animation, you also could separate the skeleton parts (e.g. the arm) or remove the torso mesh from vertex groups so the armature does not affect these skeleton parts. You could also apply the *Armature* modifier and edit or sculpt the mesh to fix errors. (Make a work copy or a backup first.)

Comment: So I need to remove the weights. I don't know how to do this. Each bone (Skeletal_Ribs.002) is its own mesh. Each bone has 96 Vertex Groups. Each Vertex Group has its own name (arm_stretch.l, arm_stretch.d, c_arm_twist_offset.l, c_arm_twist_offset.r, ect...). I'm still confused and don't know to to stop the ribs deforming when I move the arm down from T to A position.

Comment: Normally in videos they select the rig, then the mesh, then go to weight paint mode and then you are able to control control click the bones and that activates vertex groups. But that doesn't work for me. (Maybe to problem is that each bone/muscle is it's own mesh?) I try and in object mode select the Rig, shift select the mesh (ribs) then go to weight paint mode and the ribs are blue. Also, the bone that deforms badly (Skeletal_Ribs) has 68 Vertex Groups (like arm_stretch.l, arm_stretch.r, c_arm_twist_offset.l.) if that helps solve my problem...

Comment: My character has many meshes (each bone and muscle is its own mesh). In videos in object mode they select the rig, then the mesh, go to weight painting mode and they paint the mesh, then select different bone and paint some more. This doesn't work for me. Is it because of many meshes?